# ReactDND touch backend

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

Since reactDND library has been merged & upgraded from v7 to v9, react touch backed has been consolidated inside the library. Has anyone solved how to create a preview for a touch screen? I've tried to use DragPreviewImage but with no luck for touch screens.

```
  <DndProvider
      backend={isTouch ? TouchBackend : HTML5Backend}
      options={{ enableMouseEvents: true, preview: true }}
    >
```

Thanks